# Can't find System.Net.Http.HttpClient class

Tags: powershell, httpclient, powershell-5.1

I am trying to create HTTP client with PowerShell.
In some places like [this](https://gist.github.com/markekraus/a0135d0a5f52b609eda513df4db71cab) and [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Exch-Rest/2.5/Content/functions%5Cother%5CGet-HTTPClient.ps1), it shows that I need to create an object like that:

```
$client = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new()
```

But PowerShell doesn't find any class after `System.net.Http.`.
In [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) it shows that there is a class named `HttpClient` so I'm not sure why I can't see it with PowerShell.

I am using PowerShell 5.1.18362.1801.

Comment: I've added powershell-5.1 tag as the code is working for me on PowerShell 7.2.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure to load the `System.Net.Http` assembly.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
$client = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new()
```